# Merge two huge files in SFTP server Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-integration-sftp

I have 2 huge files >5gb in two different locations in an SFTP server . One way is to download the files and merge them and send it to SFTP again. But as we are using `openshift` the pods will have limited space. We are using `SpringBatch` . If I download files they will require very large space to store them.Is there any other efficient way  to merge files without downloading them and merge them over the network without downloading the files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `URLResource` with a `FlatFileItemReader` and the content will be streamed from the remote location without being downloaded to the machine where your job is running.